# Is `Box<Cat>` subtype of `Box<? extends Animal>`?

Tags: java, generics, type-systems

Java code:

```
class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Box<T> {}

public class Test {
    public void hello(Box<? extends Animal> box) {}
}


Box<Animal> box1 = new Box<Animal>();
Box<Cat> box2 = new Box<Cat>();
new Test().hello(box1);
new Test().hello(box2);
```

From [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since `box2` with type `Box<Cat>` can be used where it requires a type `Box<? extends Animal>`, can I say:

> `Box<Cat> is subtype of Box<? extends Animal>`

Actually: I'm not even sure if `Box<? extends Animal>` and `? extends Animal` are types

Comment: a `Box<? extends Animal>` may well be a `Box<Dog>` - and a `Box<Cat>` is not a subtype of a `Box<Dog>`... see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Also see http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207 - it explains this issue very well

Answer (score 5):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) states

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct
>   supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where `Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n)` is a type, are all of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - `C<S1,...,Sn>`, where `Si`contains `Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n)` (§4.5.1).

and [about *containing* described above](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

> A type argument `T1` is said to contain another type argument `T2`,
>   written `T2 <= T1`, if the set of types denoted by `T2` is provably a
>   subset of the set of types denoted by `T1` under **the reflexive and
>   transitive closure** of the following rules (where `<:` denotes subtyping
>   (§4.10)):
>
> ```
> ? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S
>
> ? extends T <= ?
>
> T <= T
>
> T <= ? extends T
>
> [...] // see these if you are interested
> ```

In your case,

```
Box<Cat>
```

we care about `Cat`. With the above, we can say that `? extends Cat` contains `Cat`. We can then say `? extends Animal` contains `? extends Cat`, since `Cat <: Animal`. So `? extends Animal` contains `Cat`. Therefore `Box<? extends Animal>` is a direct supertype of the parameterized type `Box<Cat>`

Therefore, `Box<Cat>` is a subtype of `Box<? extends Animal>`.

Comment: How `T <= T` rules works? Does this mean that `Box<Cat>` is a subtype of `Box<Cat>`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. That's how I interpret it.